# What is the fastest way to compute absolute value of integer of long long int type in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the fastest way to compute absolute value of integer of long long int type in C++ ? Is it possible to do without `if()` statement ? I was trying conversion to unsigned and then to signed again, but it doesn't work.

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? Is computing absolute values a bottleneck in your program's performance?

Comment: What do you think the cost of an `if` is in your platform? (BTW, what is your platform?)

Comment: @Keith Thompson yes because I need  to compute Manhattan distance

Comment: @Qbik: That does not answer Keith's question. His question is not why do you need to do this, but whether you need to squeeze the last bit of performance of this particular operation. How many millions of times do you need to compute the manhattan distance per second?

Comment: @David Rodríguez almost 1GB of data

Comment: @Qbik yes, but how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: The fastest way should be `llabs` from `<stdlib.h>`. Library functions clearly express your intent to readers and the compiler and is more likely to be optimized into a version tailored to your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from [Bit Twiddling Hacks, Compute the integer absolute value (abs) without branching](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs):

```
long long v; // value to abs()
long long const mask = v >> sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT - 1;

unsigned long long result = (v + mask) ^ mask;
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it requires a very specific implementation of `long long`, which while is very prevalent, isn't perfectly portable.

Comment: .. that and that in some platforms the are specific non-branching instructions to implement the ternary operator with fundamental types...

Comment: I like this answer. Would I be correct in assuming that this now means that the pipeline is guaranteed to saturate as opposed to relying on branch prediction to give you the improvements only some of the time? If that's the case then this is faster than branching.

Comment: @nonsensical: Profile. On some platforms, ternaries can be optimized to conditional moves (or, e.g. on ARM, conditional instructions), which usually execute just as fast as arithmetic instructions.

Comment: @nonsensical, you're replacing a single branch with multiple logical and arithmetic operations. You can't guarantee that it will be faster, especially if the majority of your inputs will be one sign or the other. And there's always the possibility that your compiler uses non-branching instructions in the first place.

Comment: @nneonneo Good point. I guess the depth of the pipeline is another factor to consider in gauging the benefits of using this approach. Still, it is a good one to remember. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way you can explain to me how that last line works? What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 5):

Try [`std::abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) against the ternary operator, profile, and see for yourself.

Comment: Would `std::abs` be faster than a XOR operation against `0x8000000000000000`?

Comment: @Magtheridon96 maybe not. However, `std::abs` is portable, while that bit hack isn't.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 `std::abs` would be portable. Concerning speed, I would say the same: profile and see for yourself.

Comment: Oh well, portability wins in the end. I'd profile, but I'm quite low on disk space and Visual Studio created 2GB of files last time I attempted to profile my project, so I guess I'll just leave that for another day. :P

Comment: @Magtheridon96 well, not always. You might need to squeeze performance out of an application that only runs on a specific platform. But the point about profiling still applies, of course.

Comment: @Magtheridon96: That XOR will flip the sign, but a) you don't know whether you even need to modify the input (what if it is already positive) and b) even if you do, that XOR will not give you the correct value. `-1 ^ 0x8000... != 1` (in most common platforms with two's complement)

Comment: @downvoter If there is something wrong with my answer, or it is controversial enough to merit a downvote, I would be interested in knowing so I can improve/fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `llabs`. See the [reference about `abs` functions on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/)

Comment: Why would I use this over `std::abs`?

Comment: This is what I would have used. Maybe I'm misguided.

Comment: To be clear, there's nothing wrong with this answer. However, better options do exist, and should probably be leveraged when possible.